# I need to find y and z in an extremely complicated sigma notation

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$$f\left(x\right)=\left(\sum \:_{n=0}^{x-1}1+3n+3n^2\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}$$
$$f\left(x\right)=\left(\sum \:_{n=0}^yz\right)^{\frac{1}{4}}$$
Find y and z, given that f(x) should work on all integers from (1,∞). You may use Double series but not add on another sigma notation.

Comment: Hint: $1 + 3 n + 3 n^2 = (n+1)^3 - n^3$.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see the sums of the first $m, m^2$:

$\sum\limits_{k=1}^m k=\frac{m(m+1)}{2}$

and

$\sum\limits_{k=1}^m k^2=\frac{m(m+1)(2m+1)}{4}$

Put them back to the first sum where $m=x-1$

we get that

$f^3(x)=x^3-1 $

So $f^4(x)=(x^3-1)^{\frac{4}{3}}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^y z$

On the other hand using the generalized binomial series:

$(x^3-1)^{\frac{4}{3}}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \binom{\frac{4}{3}}{n} (x^3)^{\frac{4}{3}-n}(-1)^n=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \binom{\frac{4}{3}}{n} (-1)^nx ^{4-3n}$

Finally compare the last two equation we have that:

$z=\binom{\frac{4}{3}}{n} (-1)^nx ^{4-3n}$; and $y\rightarrow \infty$